# Sending a two-dimensional array to the server and getting through Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, json, arduino

I need to send a two dimensional array to server using c arduino language . earlier i used to send through one dimensional array  like this.

```
typedef struct {
  String Name;
  String addr;
  String ttl;
}officeKownNetworks;
officeKownNetworks officeDevice;



JSONVar readings;
String KnownMacDetails() {
        while(true) {
            readings["addrDeviceUser"] = officeDevice.Name;
            readings["addr"] = officeDevice.addr;
            String jsonString = JSON.stringify(readings);
            return jsonString;
        }
        
};
```

and through spiffs i used to send that data to javascript

```
server.on("/clientsniffer", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    String json = KnownMacDetails();
    request->send(200, "application/json", json);
    json = String();
  });
```

and through promises or XML, I used to get data. but in the case of a 2-dimensional array, I am not getting how to send the data.

So basically, I have a loop where the Mac address is going to be saved in this array. of `maclist [64] [3];`

So how can I send that data to an array on the server, and how can I receive it through javascript? What parameter do I need to use?

Thank You

I am able to send a one-dimensional array to a server through JSON, but I need to know how to send a two-dimensional array to the server and receive it through Javascript.

Comment: Updated Thanks. You how can we do??

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that library, but probably something like:

```
String KnownMacDetails() {
    JSONVar array;
    for( int i = 0; i < 64; i++ ){
        JSONVar entry;
        entry["mac"]    = maclist[i][0];
        entry["ttl"]    = maclist[i][1];
        entry["status"] = maclist[i][2];

        array[i] = entry;
    }
    return JSON.stringify(array);  
}
```